# Как правильно организовать правило UrlManager

Tags: yii2

есть такое правило

```
'/serial/category/search/<query>' => '/serial/category/search',
```

и при таком запросе оно срабатывает нормально

```
serial/category/search/любовь
```

а при таком
serial/category/search/Любовь/Ненависть
не срабатывает но проблема в том что Любовь/Ненависть это реальное название сериала, и такой поисковой запрос могут оформить. Как может появиться и сериал День/Ночь можно ли как то за экранировать / в rules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

`'/serial/category/search/<query:[\/\w]+>' => '/serial/category/search',`

Я не очень уверен.

Comment: Спасибо все получилось